# Auto save after EditFrame

Tags: experience-editor

We are on Sitecore version 9.1.

Is it possible to disable automatic save and reloading the page to the experience editor after editing the component parameter in EditFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `WebEdit.AutoSaveOnEditFrame` property to "false" which is located in `.\Website\App_Config\Sitecore\Experience Editor\Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config`

```
      <!--  WEB EDIT AUTO SAVE ON EDIT FRAME
            Indicates whether whether item is automatically saved when edit frame is 
            closed after editing.
            Default value: true
      -->
      <setting name="WebEdit.AutoSaveOnEditFrame" value="false" />
```

Comment: Any idea how to achieve same behavior ' Save and Reload' if button is added to component ribbon.